# Why is there a lead (Pb) warning on extra heavy duty batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I have some batteries labelled as Extra Heavy Duty with a picture of a trashcan and the letters Pb for lead, and an x over the trashcan which I believe means not to discard in the trash. The batteries also say not for retail sale, so I suspect that they were the original batteries in some children's toys from which I pulled them out. I found on the web that the likely chemistry is zinc chloride, and I don't see any lead in the chemical reaction.

What is the source of the lead? Is it just impurities in the zinc, as can occur with zinc-galvanized hardware? I know that in the galvanization process lead is added to the kettles for metallurgical reasons. Is there something similar going on here?

Thanks

Comment: We'll need some more info to identify the type of battery. A picture would be good, and/or any text on the label, and the battery voltage. It could be a lead acid battery?

Comment: @Drew No, I've seen these on little AAA and AA batteries too. Always Chinese no-name batteries that come with a product.

Comment: If they aren't lead-acid rechargeable, perhaps they are old enough that the contacts used lead-based solder?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just a syndrome of someone buying the cheapest batteries on the market.

That has the effect of someone else producing the cheapest possible batteries.

That has the effect that someone had to send an image file to factory that prints the wrappers of the batteries, and that someone didn't have any engineer to talk to, so they just took the symbols they thought should appear on such a battery.